# Running Sierra and Leopard on MacBook Air

Tags: leopard

I just bought a new MacBook Air and want to know if I can partition the drive and add Leopard (10.5.8) so I can run my older music software.

The issue for me both the cost and I like the older versions interface better.  I still have an old PowerPC G5 which would service the Leopard software, but no current printer will support the older G5, hence my thought I could use older software, make doc PDF, then print with new OS.

Is this realistic?

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is newer than Leopard, then it's not possible.

No Mac can run an OS older than itself - the drivers for it simply weren't invented.

Your only option would be to set up a VM, using Parallels or similar; but you'd have to use Lion - the oldest user version of OS X licensed for virtualisation.
Snow Leopard Server was the first ever version you can virtualise.